# Jquery .text().length counting element's code as well as characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to detect the amount of characters in a div and do something if there is less then five:

```
var n = $("#mydiv").text().length;
if (n < 5){
      //do something
  }
```

But 'n' seems to be counting the code used for the div it self:

```
<div id="mydiv">

</div>
```

So even if there are no characters within the div: `n = 23`.

Does anyone know a way to adjust this to only count characters within the div itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trim the text to exclude the leading and trailing spaces in the text

```
var n = $.trim($("#mydiv").text()).length; //use String.trim() if you want to support IE9+
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/f2KdD/)

- [$.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)
- [String.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

Answer (score 0):

do the trim:

```
var n = $("#mydiv").text().trim().length;
```

There are new line characters even your div is empty, so that is getting in count.