# how to count typeing characters in div (contentediable)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, contenteditable

My html.

```
<div id="text" contenteditable="true" ></div>
```

My Jquery

```
count = 212
$("#text").keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 8){
       if(count === 212){
          return;
       }
       count = count + 1;
    }else{
       count = count - 1;
    }
});
```

but not work..
when i use mouse to selected
and press back space (to delete) , 
my count value doesn't matched

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to count character in div

Comment: why don't you try the `length` of value of `text`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery .text().length counting element's code as well as characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22893238/jquery-text-length-counting-elements-code-as-well-as-characters)

Comment: From a comment on one of the answers, I think this may be what you're after: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20314126/regex-highlight-part-over-19-chars

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for Character count operation:

HTML

```
 <div id="txt" contenteditable="true" ></div>
 <span id="count"></span>
```

JS:

```
              $(document).ready(function(){

              $('#txt').keyup(function(){
                  alert("hello");
                  var el=$(this);
                  alert(el.text().length);
                  $('#count').text(el.text().length);

                });

});
```

CSS:

```
#txt
{
    width:137px;
    height:100px;
   background-color:black;
    color:white;
}

#count
{
    width:55px;
    background-color:blue;
    height:15px;
    color:white;
}
```

Here fiddle [`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/vengatesh/qsu52b8j/) for your reference

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `length` of value of `text`, see below code

```
count = 212
$("#text").keydown(function(e){
  if(count === 212){
       return;
   }
   count = $(this).text().length;    
});
```

Comment: This will never work right? As count is always 212, it will never come to the new count..??

Comment: i done! with my new script.. , Thank for help  "Deer-Outdoor "

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use HTML maxlength?

http://jsfiddle.net/yne738q6/1/

```
<input type='text' class='count' maxlength='212' />

$('.count').keyup(function(e){
    console.log($('.count').val().length);
});
```

It will never go over 212 characters.

Comment: you ever see on twitter post
user can typing more than max of length
i want to do like that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it a small jQuery plugin, you can adapt from the code below (which displays the char count above the element):

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.countChar = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      var $elem = $(this);
      var $label = $("<div></div>").insertBefore($elem);
      $elem.on("focus keyup", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $label.html($elem.text().length);
      });
    });
  };
}(jQuery));
```

See example here: http://jsbin.com/deloc/3/